# Run google apps script only once after "IF" criteria met, once per month

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below code in Google Sheets send an email to myself when the monthly family budget balance goes below 10% of the monthly budget total, this is checked with a time-driven trigger that runs once daily. What I would like it to do now is run just once per month but run every month that one time, i.e. when the "IF" criteria (monthly budget balance below 10%) is met in November, it does not run again in November, but does "reset" for December and run when December's monthly budget then goes below 10%. FYI, if it helps, the values in cells A7 & A8 in the 'Budget' sheet automatically update to the current month's values via formulas in the sheet, not a script.

Thanks for your help and let me know if there is anything I can clarify!

```
function FinalBudget() {
  // Fetch the current budget figure
  var monthBudgetPercentRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Budget').getRange("A7"); 
  var monthBudgetPercent = monthBudgetPercentRange.getValue();
  var monthBudgetValueRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Budget').getRange("A8"); 
  var monthBudgetValue = monthBudgetValueRange.getValue();
  var doIt = true;
  // Checks amount of non-fixed budget spent percentage
  if (monthBudgetPercent < 0.1) {
    // Sends an email when non-fixed budget spent is less than 10%, gives percent & euro amount remaining in subject line  
    var recipientsTO = "email1@gmail.com";
    var recipientsCC = "email2@gmail.com";
    var Subject = "We have "+monthBudgetPercent*100+"% / "+monthBudgetValue+" € left of our non-fixed budget remaining for this month";
    var message = "Check budget sheet.";
    var html = message;

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipientsTO,
    cc: recipientsCC,
    subject: Subject,
    htmlBody: html
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the last time an email was sent. (I'd use the [Properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties).)
2. Check if the current date is within the same month as the last email sent.
3. If different month, send the email and update the last email sent date.
4. Use a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to check your budget regularly–I'd guess daily. (The trigger frequency should be similar to the data update frequency.)

Comment: Thanks Diego, for point 4 I have updated my question to include that the script already runs on a time-driven trigger, running once daily. For points 1 - 3 I'd have to see if I am able to do this - I am a google apps script novice!

Comment: It's a great way to learn @RyanSmith! Let us know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks Diego, let me give it a go, much appreciated if I can follow up if any issues. Cheers!